# Need to convert entire column from string format to date format from a Dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert an entire column from a Dataframe from a string to date format.  Does anyone have any recommendations on how to do this?

I've successfully been able to change one element of this using strptime, but not sure the best way to apply this to the entire column:

Sample of the raw Data:

```
2016/06/28 02:13:51
```

In:

```
Var1 = Dataframename['columnname'][0]
temp = datetime.datetime.strptime(Var1, '%Y/%m/%d  %H:%M:%S')
temp
```

Out:

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 28, 2, 13, 51)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'b':['2016/06/28 02:13:51','2016/06/28 02:13:51','2016/06/28 02:13:51'],
                   'a':[4,5,6]})

print (df)
   a                    b
0  4  2016/06/28 02:13:51
1  5  2016/06/28 02:13:51
2  6  2016/06/28 02:13:51

df['b'] = pd.to_datetime(df.b)
print (df)
   a                   b
0  4 2016-06-28 02:13:51
1  5 2016-06-28 02:13:51
2  6 2016-06-28 02:13:51
print (df.dtypes)
a             int64
b    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: another column of my raw data has the format hhh:mm:ss , I am having difficulty utilizing the .to_datetime function on this even when trying to specify the format.  Any recommendations for this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this

```
import datetime
data['colname']=data['colname'].apply(lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```